# Raspberry PI: Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address

Tags: python, linux, debugging, raspberry-pi

I am having an issue with a Python script that is running on a Raspberry Pi. Frankly, the script initially runs perfectly fine and then after a certain period of time (typically >1 hour) the computer either freezes or shuts down. I am not sure if this is a software or a hardware issue. The only clue I have so far is the following error message that appeared one time when the computer froze:

[9798.371860] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address e50b405c

How should this message be interpreted? What could be a good way of keep debugging the code? Any help is relevant since I am fairly new to programming and have run out of ideas on how to troubleshoot this issue..

Here is also some background to what the Python code intends to do (not sure if it makes a difference though). In short, every other second it registers the temperature through a sensor, creates a JSON file and saves it, sends this JSON object through cURL (urllib) to a web API, receives a new JSON file, changes switches based on the data in this file, sleeps for 2 seconds and repeats this process.

Thanks!

Comment: There will be much more in the kernel logs than just that single line. Any chance you can get dmesg output or /proc/kmsg?

Comment: The problem is that the whole computer freezes and goes black so I can't view any output. I can always restart the computer and get the dmesg file and probably also the kmsg one but I don't know if that is of any help.. Is it possible to somehow save log files and get access to them after rebooting?

Comment: dmesg is not a file. It is a command that read kmsg. kmsg is an infinite long file. What kind of extra drivers do you have added? Otherwise it is quite unlikely that the kernel would throw such an issue.

Comment: Has anyone resolved this already? It's 2018 now and I encounter this error on an Raspberry Pi Zero.